# jQuery.noConflict(true) - Causing Marionette code to break

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, marionette, conflict

I have the following code:

```
    jq1111 = jQuery.noConflict(true);

    (function($, jQuery){
        // bunch of js libraries (backbone, underscore, etc)
        ...
        Marionette.Callbacks = function(){
            this._deferred = Marionette.$.Deferred();
            this._callbacks = [];
        };
        ...
    })(jq1111, jq1111)
```

I am seeing an error where it's saying $ is undefined in `this._deferred = Marionette.$.Deferred();`.

I've defined $ in the function and all other instances of $ seem to be working with no issue. Any idea why this is happened or how to get around it please?

Note that using jQuery.noConflict() without "true" works fine, but I've defined jQuery in the new function call so there shouldn't be a difference...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to just change my code to do the following:

```
(function($, jQuery){
    // bunch of js libraries (backbone, underscore, etc)
    ...
})($, jQuery)

jq1111 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

I'm not sure why the standard is to define noConflict() before you define your jQuery, then use your definition in the function.
In all honesty it makes a lot more sense to do it this way.

Comment: Marinette.$ references global $ or jQuery. If you call $.noConflict(true) beforehand, Marionette.$ will be undefined.

Comment: I see, thank you for the information. Is there no way to over ride it?

Comment: Yes: dont pass any argument to noConflict.